# COMSOL on Ubuntu (10.04 LTS and 11.04)

Tags: comsol, parallel-computing

I am running into a problem with COMSOL 4.2.0.187 on Ubuntu (both 10.04 LTS and 11.04). When using the option `-np x` with `x` > 1, COMSOL crashes systematically after a short, yet random amount of time with the following error:

```
> [thread 140538491361024 also had an error] terminate called without an active exception 
> Aborted
```

When setting only one working process (`-np 1`), the error disappear. The COMSOL support staff  told me that there must be a problem with the threading libraries. I suspect that they just have no idea what to tell me.

Do you guys have any idea as how to solve this problem? Have you ever encountered such an error with COMSOL or another piece of software?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Off-topic in my opinion

Comment: well, COMSOL is a core computational software package. This might well be a server-side problem, but how can i know for sure? There are good chances that this will be useful to people using COMSOL in the future. Plus: the guys at SuperUser and ServerFault were unable to answer my question (and didn't care).

Comment: I get that, but I wouldn't want to see the site flooded with questions about setting up software packages (e.g. OpenFOAM doesn't compile, Ansys is complaining about my license, PETSc is missing libraries, ...). Just my two cents.

Answer (score 5):

That thread ID looks bogus to me, which leads me to believe someone is writing over memory. I think the most helpful thing you could do for the COMSOL guys is to run this under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and send them the output.

Comment: I have to say that the COMSOL guys are not as supportive and helpful as one would wish for such an expensive piece of software.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to be running the latest version of COMSOL. You might want to install the latest updates and try again. See http://www.comsol.com/support/updates/comsol42p3/  I'm able to run comsol -np x (x > 1) on a Scientific Linux 6.0 without problems.

Comment: 4.2.0.187 (edited the question)